# How to Render a Grails View Without a Layout

Tags: grails, sitemesh

If you have a controller action, but don't want the view to be rendered with the default layout (in my case layout/main.gsp), is there a render option you can enter into the controller action or something similar?

```
def comingSoon {
  static layout = none;  //not correct, but something like this?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view file, you might see something like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>  // delete this line
    <title>Coming Soon</title>
</head>
...
```

Remove the meta tag with the name="layout". This meta tag is the one that tells sitemesh to use the main layout

Answer (score 0):

Without more details it's difficult to say 100% what case you are in so I'll attempt to answer both.

If you are using dynamically scaffolded views then you'll need to generate the GSPs so you can remove the `<meta name="layout"` tag from them. This will keep any layout from being used.

Alternatively you could alter the scaffolding templates (within the scaffolding plugin) to include some additional logic about not applying a layout when the domain class has some static property (as your question contains).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `<meta name="layout" content="main"/>` to vanish exists layout. Or you may customize layout by edit that main.gsp page in `your-project\grails-app\views\layouts\`